# is it possible to create a redirect page with diffrent content?

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

what i need is:  create a redirect page with diffrent content (in same url) depending on source url where visitor come!
for exemple :

- Visitor X come from a href url [www.example.com/page?u=target1.com](http://www.example.com/page?u=target1.com)
- Visitor Y come from ahref url [www.example.com/page?u=target2.com](http://www.example.com/page?u=target2.com)

the redirect page for both visitors X and Y is [www.example.com/redirect-page](http://www.example.com/redirect-page) but with different content for the visitor X a (button) with a href button to target1.com
for the visitor Y a href (button) to target2.com
(sorry for my bad english, i hope get the right answer )

Comment: You can get the value of 'u' from the referrer URL and append it to the redirect URL like so `www.exemple.com/redirect-page?u=target1.com` then based on the value of 'u', you can display the related content.

Comment: is it possible to do it without adding anything on www.example.com/redirect-page****

Comment: @MohamedEssahraoui You can send a POST request if you do not want to add anything to the URL.

Answer (score 0):

1. read the query parameter

   ```
      parse_str($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'], $queries);
      $queries["u"] will be the target
   ```
2. Store the target value in session
   `$_SESSION["targetValue"] = $queries["u"]`
3. Redirect the user to /redirect-page/
4. You can show/hide/render depending on `$_SESSION["targetValue"]`

Answer (score -1):

By "redirect-page", if you mean it is actually redirecting to another 3rd page, then @ruleboy21's comment is correct.

But I think you mean "redirect-page" is the page that people are being redirected to, and you just want to add a customized "back" button to it.  If so, here is one approach:

```
if ( !empty($_GET['u'] ) {
  echo '<a href="'.htmlspecialchars($_GET['u'], ENT_QUOTES,'UTF-8').'" style="border:1px solid black;padding:2px;"> back </a>';
}
```

Which doesn't create a `<button>`, but rather an `<a>` link containing the referring page in it's href attribute, and has some styling to make it look like a button (which you can change however you want).